# On the convergence of approximate units for C*-algebras.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a non-unital C*-algebra and let $\pi : A \to \mathcal{B}(H)$ be a non-degenerate representation of $A$ (that is, $\mathrm{ span }\{\pi(a)h : a \in A, h \in H\}$ is a dense subset of $H$). Now let $(u_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be an approximate unit for $A$. A standard argument, using non-degeneracy, shows that $(\pi(u_\lambda))_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ converges strongly to $1_H$, the identity operator on $H$. There are several examples that show that $(\pi(u_\lambda))_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is not norm convergent.

However, below I will present an argument that "shows" that $(\pi(u_\lambda))_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ converges in norm to $1_H$. This is certainly at fault, but I want to make sure I understand exactly where the proof goes wrong.

**Argument:** Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $h \in H$ with $\|h\|=1$
such that
$$
\| 1_H - \pi(u_\lambda) \| < \epsilon + \| h - \pi(u_\lambda)h \|.
$$
Then, since strong convergence of $(\pi(u_\lambda))_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ implies that
$(\| h - \pi(u_\lambda)h \|)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ converges to $0$, we find $\lambda' \in \Lambda$ such that for all $\lambda \geq \lambda'$,
$$
\| h - \pi(u_\lambda)h \| < \epsilon.
$$
Thus, for any  $\lambda \geq \lambda'$, we have shown
$$
\| 1_H - \pi(u_\lambda) \| < 2\epsilon,
$$
which proves that $\pi(u_\lambda)$ converges in norm to $1_H$.
**End of argument.**

I am pretty sure that the problem in the above argument is that $h$ depends
on $\epsilon$ and therefore also $\lambda'$. Thus, the expression $\| h - \pi(u_\lambda)h \| < \epsilon$ for $\lambda \geq \lambda'$ doesn't make much sense to me. In any case, I am still not quite convinced about this and I would love to hear someone else's thoughts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is as you say. Something that often helps when in doubt with an argument like this is to consider a concrete example.

Let $A=c_0$. Then an approximate unit is given by $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^n e_k$, where $\{e_k\}$ is the canonical basis. We can think $c_0\subset\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ (or if you insist on representing on a Hilbert space you can represent all this as diagonal operators).

Now we see what happens. We have $\|1-u_n\|=1$ for all $n$. The $h$ you choose can be for instance $h=e_{n+1}$; there are many other possible choices, but they will all depend on $n$. Now you have
$$
\|1-u_n\|=\|e_{n+1}-u_ne_{n+1}\|
$$
(that is, we can even take $\epsilon=0$). And you can see that taking limit on the right does not work as your argument says, because the $h=e_{n+1}$ changing with $n$ does **not** make the norm go to zero.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Martín. Tu ejemplo me quitó la duda por completo.

Comment: ¡De nada! :) $ $